# ¿Cómo cerrar el cursor negro/blanco en android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Cursor no me deja escribir o copiar linea. Cuando utilizo el comando <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>,me permite escribir, pero luego cuando quiero copiar texto de alguna linea de código, me marca el cursor blanco/negro, nuevamente. Necesito ayuda.

[image: imagen 1]

[image: imagen 2]

Answer (score 4):

Para quitar el cursor que indicas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo realizas con la tecla <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Pero esto no es la causa por la cual no puedas escribir en tu archivo, me parece que tienes el modo "read-only" activo, debes deshabilitarlo para poder editar tu archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estuve en un problema algo similar

**SOLUCION: En tu pestaña(ventana) donde estas programando selecciona cualquier linea y presiona Las siguientes Teclas.
(SHIFT + 0)**

[image: Antes]
Antes -  y  - despues
[image: Despues]

La barra ↑ gruesa no me dejaba seleccionar bien nada ni digitar,  con eso lo solucione.

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea valiosa, explica en que consisten los dos modos del cursor, su utilidad y aplicación, así como el modo de pasar de uno a otro. Si no, todo seguirá siendo un misterio sin explicación, y tu respuesta no será de utilidad a nadie más.

Comment: @Frank esa explicación que pusiste en el comentario es muy valiosa, te animo a que edites la respuesta que tiene mucho potencial y ahi lo agregues :)

Answer (score 0):

Solución para mac:
Mi teclado no tiene la tecla Insert, pero esa función la podemos activar escribiendo **control+command+s** (^⌘S). Hay que hacerlo dentro de cada uno de los archivos que componen el proyecto (dentro de los archivos .java y .xml) y ya esta. Espero que les funcione.